# VLOOKUP on multiple columns

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

Is it possible to do a formula which will look in 3 different columns for a vlookup match to return the result. e.g. Looking up part number A, which could be in column A, B or C and want to return result in D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not that difficult, providing your lookup_value appears **precisely once** within that range.

For example, with a range of A2:D100 and a search value in e.g. G2:

=INDEX(D2:D100,SUMPRODUCT((A2:C100=G2)*(ROW(A2:C100)-MIN(ROW(A2:C100))+1)))

Regards

Comment: This does work but I cannot copy the forumula down as"excel ran out of resources while attemping to calculate one or more formulas, as a result these formulas cannot be evaluated." Does 10 rows then stops.Theres approx 1000 rows in the worksheet.

Comment: And it's only columns A to C that you've set the range to? And what row number did you enter for the end range?

Comment: =INDEX('Copy Large Stock Pack'!E:E,SUMPRODUCT(('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B:D=A2)*(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B:D)-MIN(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B:D))+1)))

Comment: SUMPRODUCT with entire column references is not a good idea, since that formula calculates over all 1 million+ rows, whether beyond your last non-blank cell or not. Try using a suitable upper bound, e.g. E2:E1000, etc.

Comment: =INDEX('Copy Large Stock Pack'!E$1:E$1000,SUMPRODUCT(('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000=A3)*(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000)-MIN(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000))+1))) seems to work, only issue its returning a random result where there is no match ?Really appreciate help.

Comment: Ok. Use: =IF(SUMPRODUCT(0+('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000=A3))=0,"No Match",INDEX('Copy Large Stock Pack'!E$1:E$1000,SUMPRODUCT(('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000=A3)*(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000)-MIN(ROW('Copy Large Stock Pack'!B$1:D$1000))+1))))

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer would be that you can't.

VLOOKUP will always search in the first column of the table_array that you pass to the function. You could try to create a formula that will use the `#N/A` result from the VLOOKUP if no match is found to search for the value in the next column (and so on).